# Convert a closed google Doc to a PDF and attach it in an email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet form that takes its information and places it into a document which then needs to be converted to a pdf and sent as an attachment.

I have the document 'Template' ready to go but don't know how to convert a document that is not open as a tab (aka I cant use DocumentApp).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `DriveApp` to access files in Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DocumentApp from another script, not just the script which is bound to a doc. Let's say your doc template is document ID `abcdefghijklmnop`...

```
// If you have a template, first make a copy
var docCopy = DriveApp.getFileById('abcdefghijklmnop').makeCopy();
var copyId = docCopy.getId();
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);

// Do whatever you need to modify the doc here.

// Now we're done, and `doc` needs to turn into a PDF
var pdfContent = doc.getAs('application/pdf');
var draftMail = GmailApp.createDraft('william@example.com',
                                     'Email title', 'Pls see attached', 
                                     {
                                         attachments: [pdfContent.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
                                         name: 'Converted doc content'
                                     });
// Now send the mail
draftMail.send();
```